# How to attach vpc link to get method in api gateway via cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation, aws-opsworks

I am trying to create a api gateway via cloudformation which use a vpc link to an internal beanstalk network load balancer:

Here is my code to create vpc link:

```
  VpcLink:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::VpcLink
  Properties:
      Description: vpc link
      Name: channel-vpc-link
      TargetArns:
          - !ImportValue channel-dns-arn
```

and here is my api gtw code:

```
GetMethod:
Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
DependsOn: VpcLink
Properties:
  AuthorizationType: NONE
  HttpMethod: GET
  #RequestParameters:
  #  method.request.path.proxy: true
  Integration:
    Type: HTTP
    IntegrationHttpMethod: GET
    Uri:
      Fn::Join:
      - ''
      - - "http://"
        - ${stageVariables.channelUrl}
        - "/channels"
        - "/stories"
    IntegrationResponses:
    - StatusCode: 200
      ResponseParameters:
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
      ResponseTemplates:
        application/json: ''
    RequestTemplates:
      application/json: ''
  ResourceId: !Ref ChannelsStoriesPath
  RestApiId:
    Ref: RestApi
  MethodResponses:
  - StatusCode: 200
    ResponseParameters:
        method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true
```

which works fine but the problem is I am not able to find a way to attach the vpc link I created earlier in the get method code. How can I set the get method through vpc link?

I found this link but was not helpful at all

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=275511

Answer (score 0):

Support for setting VPCLink in AWS::ApiGateway::Method is work in progress. As of now supported option is to use swagger template to create RestAPI with VPCLink integration

Comment: I think @Vishal is talking about this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-api-with-vpclink-using-swagger.html